# CRUD Rest API related resource

Tags: reactjs, rest, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

First, I sorry if my question have already was requested before. But I have google, read many article about a month but still not satisfy.

My situation quite special. Let say I have two table: **Ticket** and **Member** with 1:n relationship. I use React, .NET 5, Entity Framework Core and rest to communicate. But the special is I not explicit config its relation through Entity Framework Core. It mean in database, table Member is still have foreign key(ticketId) reference to Ticket. But not show in the code.

The problem come when I try to create a Ticket. Because the Ticket have always contain list of Member. Currently I have two way to do it.

1. Define a route like **api/tickets** and send a object contain all the data back that route I need to be create. Example:
   `ticket:{id: 1, .... , members: []}`.
2. Define 2 separate route **api/tickets** and **api/members** and send the single data to each route for create.

The first approach is make sure that data always success or fail same time(I use transaction in backend to do this). But it seem not best practice with rest.
The second approach is seem follow the best practice. But what happen if one of these action was fail. I can't rollback like the first.

So my question is how can I deal with it. It mean I want to follow the best practice of Rest and also need data integrity. I really really appreciate that. It help me a lot to solve my current problem.

Answer (score 0):

Relation between member and ticket could be 1:n.

1 member could has n ticket.

1 ticket could belongs to 1 member

so member class contains a list of tickets. For rest, you could define an end point like api/tickets/create that get a member object contains tickets and member info. you should handle buying a ticket logic inside your rest api and separating this operation into two api is not best practice and only inject complication to your business logic.

Comment: So handle logic another resource in endpoint of another is good in rest? I think an endpoint belong to one resource should be handle logic for only that resource.

Comment: assume rest endpoint as a presentation layer. endpoint is not related to your business logic or service layer

Comment: Thanks. I'll carefully consider your recommendation